# Making styling change when a different element is hovered over

Tags: html, css

Sorry if the heading seems confusing I just didn't how to describe my situation.

I am using bootstrap and I have a class which is `.navbar-inverse` when this is hovered over I want the .navbar-inverse a tags to have a `border-color` of *black*.

Is this possible to do in CSS?

Comment: Yes if your `a` tag is a chiid of `.navbar-inverse`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes they are

Comment: `.navbar-inverse:hover a {border: 1px solid #000;}` try that out

Comment: @Mr.Alien Perfect! Can you submit as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, if your element having a `class` of `.navbar-inverse` has `a` tags as child, you can use a selector like

```
.navbar-inverse:hover a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Note that applying `border` on `hover` will make your elements move IF they don't have initial border set so in that case you can use something like

```
.navbar-inverse a {
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* or replace transparent 
                                      with any hex you want */
}
```

and then use the above `:hover` selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a simple hover function then add your general styling under .navbar-inverse and for hover add your styling under

```
.navbar-inverse:hover {
    border-color: black;
}
```

Does that answer your question?